# combine 2 parts of arrays to 1

Tags: c#, arrays

lets say i have a

```
int[] x = new int[8] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int[] y = new int[8] {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
```

and i want a new array with with the 3th and 4th element of y  + the x array

```
int[] xy = new int[10];
```

is there a way to do something like this: xy = y[2]+y[3]+x so i would become:

```
 xy = {6,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

i thought something like this should work but it doesn't

```
 Array.Copy(y, 0, x1, 2, 2);
 Array.Copy(x, 2, x1, 0, 8);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your start index and end index are along with each other or separated by `1` then you can do:

```
int[] xy = y.Skip(2).Take(2).Concat(x).ToArray();
```

Remember arrays index are 0 based.

If you have specific indices with no pattern , for example 3rd and 7th, then use [@Blorgbeard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062727/961113)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var xy = new [] { y[2], y[3] }.Concat(x).ToArray();
```